# Did I Break the Build?

Tags: ros, ros-release, release, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on releasing my stacks to electric (since that's what they've been most tested on) and I got this email.

> Internal failure release system. Please notify leibs and kwc @willowgarage.com:
> Problem fetching yaml info for object_recognition None (https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition-None/object_recognition-None.yaml)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):

> ```
> blah blah blah
> raise Exception("Problem fetching yaml info for %s %s (%s)"%(stack_name, stack_version, url))
> ```
>
> Exception: Problem fetching yaml info for object_recognition None (https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/object_recognition/object_recognition-None/object_recognition-None.yaml)
>
> None

> http://build.willowgarage.com/job/debbuild-build-debs-electric-lucid-i386/1179/

Upon viewing the link there, I see my changes (#1 and #12) but I'm unsure if this is my fault. Is this something I should fix?

Also, (possibly unrelated) what relation does the above page have to this page: [the electric build status page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html) (as linked from the [release wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/release))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44057/did-i-break-the-build?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, object_recognition had an invalid version it should have been null not None.  Fixed now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1